# Retrieve users from serialize-array of ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, serialization, ruby-on-rails-4

I'n my Rails app there's a minor feature where Users will be able to reference other users. To accomplish this, I need to have a simple column in user table that stores the ids for the referenced users. I then use the ids to retrieve and display the referenced users.

I figured [Serialize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class) was the best way to go, but I'm having trouble retrieving **all** the ids from the array that looks currently simply like this `21,22,23,24,25`.

Currently I find the users with:

```
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @references = User.find(@user.references)
```

But in my view, for example, with `@references.name`, only first one comes up. And that seems to be all I can do, as each block throws an undefined method error.

Any ideas? Also if there's more efficient way to achieve this than serialize, I'm all ears. All insight into this is welcome and appreciated.

Comment: As an aside, if the `User.find(@user.references)` _was_ returning multiple instances, then your subsequent `@references.name` would throw an undefined method error because you're trying to get the `name` property of an ActiveRecord Relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to approach this with an *association*, as described in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

However, the problem you're encountering could be explained if you had not declared `references` to be a "serialized" field, as the SQL will match '21,22,23,24,25' to '21'. Try the following to see this in action:

```
User.find('21,22,23,24,25')
```

and compare that to:

```
User.find([21,22,23,24,25])
```

which is what you should see if `references` has been serialized properly.

Note also that the serialization only works for *future* values stored. If you have something in the database that you've written earlier, it won't be serialized properly upon extraction.

Comment: As in user HABTM users? I was under the impression that it is quite messy for such a simple function.

Comment: As in HABTM (if you want to traverse back through the relationship) or `has_many through:` if you don't. On the contrary, I think associations are quite clean and fiddling with lists is messy, but I guess it's subjective.

Comment: Wow, I've tried everything, but it doesn't seem to work. I believe that the lacking comes from my part, though, as I'm not quite familiar at all with serialize. However, if you say associations are just as good and not less, that's the way I believe I will go, as I know more about them and to think of it, `has_many through:` might be quite natural for this. Even so, I think redirecting to a solution is worthy of an accepted answer.

Comment: I hate to leave this unresolved. It really should work with serialized attributes. Have you confirmed that you're getting an array back from `@user.references`?

Comment: That's actually what I think was wrong with it, it seemed to be string, even though I implemented `serialize :references` in the User model and the column was `text` type. That's all I thought was required.

Comment: Would you mind sharing: a) your `serialize` statement, and b) an example of a stored `references` value from your database (e.g. as extracted with SQL)? If the serialization is working, YAML should be stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
@user = User.find(params[:id)
@references = User.where(id: @user.references).all
```

should work, example:

```
[4] pry(main)> User.where(id: [1,2,3]).all.count
DEPRECATION WARNING: Relation#all is deprecated. If you want to eager-load a relation, you can call #load (e.g. `Post.where(published: true).load`). If you want to get an array of records from a relation, you can call #to_a (e.g. `Post.where(published: true).to_a`). (called from __pry__ at (pry):4)
  User Load (3.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN (1, 2, 3)
=> 3
```

Comment: Hmm, quite logical, but still seems to retrieve only one, the first in the array.

Comment: No, returns an array of all referenced users :)

Comment: @dosadnizub If `find(@user.references)` only gives 1 result, then `where(id: @user.references)` will only give 1 result.

Comment: My, you're right, I had no idea it does that :) However, it does return a list of User instances referenced by IDs stored in user.references. Are you sure @user.references is OK? The code otherwise does what its supposed to do

Comment: You need to address your comments to me specifically or I won't get a notification, since I'm not the OP. Actually, if `@user.references` is just a comma-separated string, both `where` and `find` will just return the User instance whose id matches the first integer in the string.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin, I understood the OP that the field is serialized, meaning that the getter returns an array of integers, it's a simple variation both ways (`User.where(id: @user.references.split(/,/).map(&:to_i)).all`), did we understand each other? :)

Comment: I know that's what the OP said. :-) I'm suggested he may not have implemented it properly, per my answer, and that `@user.references` is returning a string.

Comment: In other words, the problem is not with `find` vs. `where` but with the value of `@user.references`. Yes, if it's a string, I understand he can do the serialization manually. This comes down to there being two parts to the question: a) Why isn't what I'm doing working, and b) Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, I believe both of your code were fine, but there was something I was doing wrong on my part. I will not bother you more helping me with that, and instead do this with functions I'm more familiar with. Even so, I'm quite thankful indeed for both of your help. Thank you!